# Idiomatic way of "updating" a given key in a Clojure map?

Tags: dictionary, clojure, merge

Say we have a map that looks something like:

```
(def m {:a {:foo "bar"}})
```

Now we'd like to update the key :a in m with some new values:

```
(def vs {:baz "qux"})
```

If this were Python we could do something like:

```
>>> d = {'a': {'foo': 'bar'}}
>>> d['a'].update({'baz': 'qux'})
>>> d
{'a': {'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 'qux'}}
```

The simplest Clojure equivalent I found was to define a function like this:

```
(defn update-key
  "
  Updates a given key `k` over a map `m` with a map of values `vs`.
  "
  [k m vs]
  (assoc m k (merge (k m) vs)))
```

Which is then invoked like:

```
(update-key :a m vs)
; => {:a {:foo "bar" :baz "qux"}}
```

So my question is: What is the most idiomatic and correct way to achieve the same functionality as the `update()` method Python dicts provide?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`assoc-in`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/assoc-in):

```
(def m {:a {:foo "bar"}})

(assoc-in m [:a :foo] "qux")
; => {:a {:foo "qux"}}

(assoc-in m [:a :baz] "qux")
; => {:a {:foo "bar", :baz "qux"}}
```

[`update-in`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/update-in) is similar, and might be worth looking at too. This might actually be closer to your Python example:

```
(def m {:a {:foo "bar"}})
(def vs {:baz "qux"})

(update-in m [:a] merge vs)
; => {:a {:foo "bar", :baz "qux"}}
```

---

**Update:**

Even if the key is a variable value (not a compile-time constant) you can still use both `update-in` and `assoc-in` by putting the variable in the vector:

```
(def m {:a {:foo "bar"}})
(def k' :baz)
(def v' "qux")

(assoc-in m [:a k'] v')
; => {:a {:foo "bar", :baz "qux"}}
```

You can also build the *keys* vector programatically:

```
(def m {:a {:foo "bar"}})
(def k' :baz)
(def v' "qux")

(let [ks (conj [:a] k')]
  (assoc-in m ks v'))
; => {:a {:foo "bar", :baz "qux"}}
```

Comment: Ah perfect, `update-in` should do exactly what I want (`assoc-in` would be even better but I don't know the key-name in `vs` ahead of time). For some reason I'm not finding the docs to be particularly elucidating: I had read about both `assoc-in` and `update-in` but didn't understand how to merge into the correct key. Thanks!

Comment: @maxcountryman - Not knowing the keys/values statically isn't an issue. See my updates for examples on using non-static keys.

Comment: Thanks for the update. That might be a little cumbersome as compared to `update-in` for what I'm doing. If I have to separate the key and value with `assoc-in`, the code is going to be less concise than if I use `update-in` I think. But it's good to see it can be done!